# Converting text to local language - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I am implementing text to speech calls with laravel and Nexmo. In the application, i am able to place calls to my clients with `English language' as below. The text placed to my customers is

**To add a reply, please leave a message after the beep, then press the pound key**

Is there a way to convert the text from english to my native language ? So the call will be in the language i converted to ?

Please help? Beginner with this

```
$currentHost = 'http://abc123.ngrok.io';
Nexmo::calls()->create([
    'to' => [[
        'type' => 'phone',
        'number' => $cc->user->phone_number
    ]],
    'from' => [
        'type' => 'phone',
        'number' => config('services.nexmo.sms_from')
    ],
    'answer_url' => [$currentHost.'/webhook/answer/'.$entry->id],
    'event_url' => [$currentHost.'/webhook/event']
]);

    return response()->json([
        [
            'action' => 'talk',
            'text' => $ticket->content
        ],
        [
            'action' => 'talk',
            'text' => 'To add a reply, please leave a message after the beep, then press the pound key',
            'voiceName' => 'Brian'
        ],
        [
            'action' => 'record',
            'endOnKey' => '#',
            'beepStart' => true
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: @J.Doe, does it support every language or it has some specified languages?

Comment: are you need auto translate(via google translate, for example) your messages or custom translation?

Comment: @J.Doe google translate api doesn't have my language so i have to do a custom translation

Comment: laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization  this support any language, read this link